# Using discord.py to create a server and get an invite

Tags: python, discord.py

Ive made a guild using discord.py, but I cant work out how to get an invite to that guild! How can I get an invite?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't create a guild / server with a bot account. Could you clarify more on what you're trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: @Axiumin theres a command "client.create_guild" that made the guild and when i use "client.get_guilds()" it shows the server in the list

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. Sorry for saying that you can't make a guild with a bot account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can get the invite of the new guild by running `create_invite()`. [Documentation link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.create_guild)

```
my_guild = await client.create_guild("My Server!") # replace "client" with the name of your discord client variable

my_guild_invite = await my_guild.text_channels[0].create_invite() # makes invite for the first text channel and returns an Invite class

print(my_guild_invite.code)
```